# Android Studio throwing warnings on everything

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

The first project I created since I updated Android Studio to 2.3, I get that everything on MainActivity is marked with a warning. At first I thought it was because I was creating the project inside another folder within AndroidStudioProjects, so I corrected that but still no dice.

Here's a picture of MainActivity:
[image: Studio Warnings]

I get errors like **package-info.java file missing** or **Single class import blablabla**, or **package name too long** (even though I once tried with a very short one) and more.

I updated Android SDK tools but nothing changed. One thing to notice is that previously created projects do work as normal, and even now I keep working on them. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RajeshK It happened a long time ago, but as much as I can remember is that I waited for an update.

Comment: OK. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove support library (replace extends AppCompatActivity to extends Activity). Then Sync Project and Clean

Comment: The warnings are beyond the scope of the Activity class so that won't work. Of course I did give it a try and it didn't work, as expected

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project that may remove your warning problem.

Comment: Thank you! Just did, no dice.